# how/when Jotunheim was created precisely?

Tags: norse, folklore

I can’t find anything on the origin of Jotunheim. If it was linked, like Muspellheim, to Nilfheim in any way… and I’m not sure how did Ymir arrived in it… I guess it could be unknown like many other details of the Norse mythology, but at least I can ask a question…

Comment: When you can't find anything… what can you find, and where does that start to fail?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the creation myth as described on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norse_cosmology) I would infer that Jotunheim was created when the gods Odin, Vili, and Vé created the Earth from Ymir's body, and used Ymir's eyelashes* to separate Midgard from the outlying lands (which would be Jotunheim).

Ymir had come into being in Ginunngagap from the interaction between the ice of Niflheim and the fire from Muspelheim.

* Or eyebrows according to [another source](https://mythologysource.com/norse-creation-myth/)